# Crontab execute the command but the ruby script is not running

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm, cron

I've set a crontab for my ruby script.

```
crontab -l
12 10 * * * /bin/bash  -c 'cd /home/user/path/ && /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/ruby  -rubygems script.rb'
```

the command `/bin/bash  -c 'cd /home/user/path/ && /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/ruby  -rubygems script.rb'` runs well.

And in cron, cron is executing the command (I checked the syslog:

```
sudo tail  /var/log/syslog
(user) CMD (/bin/bash  -c 'cd /home/user/path/ && /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/ruby  -rubygems script.rb')
```

)

But the script is not executing exactly. I'm not getting the expected out put from it.

What may be the cause of the issue? It'll be grate if some one can help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
12 10 * * * /bin/bash  -c 'source /home/user/.rvm/scripts/rvm && cd /home/user/path/ && /home/user/.rvm/bin/ruby-1.9.2-p136 -rubygems script.rb'
```

Comment: Good answer. When you login to bash from a terminal it automatically runs some scripts to setup your environment (usually including the "rvm" ruby environment setup). "cron" just runs exactly what it finds in the cron file and does not automatically run any environment setup scripts.

Comment: @Sayuj: That just runs all the usual rvm initialization stuff that you'd normally get with a login shell.

Comment: Good answer. Here is a full blog post on the subject: http://danielsz.posterous.com/how-to-run-rvm-scripts-as-cron-jobs

Comment: this didnt work for me, i used `12 10 * * * /bin/bash  -c 'source /home/user/.rvm/scripts/rvm && cd /home/user/script/folder && /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3 script.rb'` i used `which ruby` to get the ruby path used in cron

Comment: worked when i used `source /home/user/.rvm/environments/ruby-2.3.3` instead of `source /home/user/.rvm/scripts/rvm`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .rvmrc file in your project to setup ruby version for you project. Then you need to tell rvm to trust rvmrc file in ~/.rvmrc

```
rvm_trust_rvmrcs_flag=1
```

this will disable prompt and your cron will not hang.

Answer (score 1):

Try running env -i $SHELL --norc in terminal and then run the ruby script. The terminal will have the same environment as the cron